# Progress bar while clicking buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a form I'm creating, and I'll have some sections that will apear from right to left, on top of that and fixed is a bar, that should increase in width each time I click on continue to go to the next question. that way user will know he's progressing. I can't make work my progress bar, can you help me figure out why?

HTML

```
<div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
</div> 

<div class="questionsContainer">

<div class="section one">
    <p class="sectionTitle">This is the First Question?</p>
    <div class="buttonContinue" id="section2">CONTINUE</div>
</div>

<div class="section two">
    <p class="sectionTitle">Aja! time for the Second one!!</p>
    <div class="buttonContinue" id="section3">CONTINUE</div>
</div>

<div class="section three">
    <p class="sectionTitle">Another Question? 3 so far?</p>
    <div class="buttonContinue" id="section4">CONTINUE</div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }

    .progress-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4px;
        background: transparent!important;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 99;
    }

    .progress-bar {
        height: 4px;
        background: #4ce4ff;
        width: 10%;
    }

    header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: fuchsia;
    }

    .questionsContainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100% - 200px);
        position: absolute;
        background-color: lime;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: black;
    }

    .section {
        background-color: purple;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .one {
        position: absolute;
        right: auto;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }

    .two {
        position: absolute;
        right: -100%;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }

    .three {
        position: absolute;
        right: -100%;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }

    .sectionTitle {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .buttonContinue {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 20px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100px;
    }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('section2').onclick = function(){
$('.one').css('right','100%');
$('.two').css('right','auto');
}   

document.getElementById('section3').onclick = function(){
$('.two').css('right','100%');
$('.three').css('right','auto');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#section2").click(addVisit);
$("#section3").click(addVisit);
$("#section4").click(addVisit);
});

function addVisit(){
     var progressTag = $('#myBar');
     count ++;
     progressTag.css('width', count * 10 + "%");
});

</script>
```

Comment: have you declared `count` in a global scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that the `count` variable has not been created and given a value initially.

I have optimized your code a bit and this is how I did it:

```
var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#section2, #section3, #section4").click(function() {
    $('#myBar').css('width', ++count * 10 + "%");
  });
});
```

I also added `transition: all 1s;` for animated CSS transition.

**[Here is your updated code in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxbhc276/)**

Comment: this is excelleng @Ahs N thanks! but what if I like to split the number of progress between the amount of <div class="section"> ? so if I have 5 something like:
$('#myBar').css('width', 100% / number of <div class="section"> available);?

Comment: @EuryKellhing `$(".section").length` should give you the number of such sections available :)

Comment: thanks @Ahs N so I've tried this 

var sectionsCounter = $("div[class*='section']").length;

and now

$('#myBar').css('width', 100 / sectionsCounter + "%");

it works! :) I have 3 sections so the bar increases 33.3% but when I click next continue button, it doesn't increase another 33.3%, can you tell me why? thanks!!

Comment: @EuryKellhing Because the value of `100 / sectionsCounter` is always _33.3%_, therefore the value never changes

Comment: thanks @Ahs N I've tried changing the var count = 100 / sectionsCounter; and then $('#myBar').css('width', ++count + "%"); but now after second click it only increments few pixels instead of another 33%. hhhehhehe I think I'm not doing right

Comment: @EuryKellhing If you combine the `counter` variable and the _number_ of sections you have, you can do it like [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0dfsry4/)